# Fullcalendar : minTime wrongly calculate fc-not-start

Tags: javascript, css, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler, fullcalendar-3

I am using the Fullcalendar library, scheduler module.

I use minTime properties and set it to: '06:00:00' inside of view definition (so that "day is not start with midnight").

But when I that, the calendar elements that starts before 6h has a class `fc-not-start` even when they are in the middle of the calendar...

How to handle this?

### EDIT :

Some additional information:

Fullcalendar version: v3.9.0

`fc-not-start` : This class should have calendar (scheduled) elements that are not started in this view. (The start is invisible). This is needed because, if element has some rounded corners, border,... it should't have on the left side if start is not visible. (Or if you want to display icon, that you are not looking at full element)

Example: 
Inside the red square, this is a right use of `fc-not-start`

[image]

This is the wrong use of the `fc-not-start`

[image]

The `fc-not-start` should calculate itself inside fullcalendar library and it is working, until I add the parameter  `minTime` in view.

### EDIT 2:

I create minimal code to see the problem

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <title>Demo</title>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/fullcalendar.css' />
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/scheduler.css' />
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.1.3/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-MCw98/SFnGE8fJT3GXwEOngsV7Zt27NXFoaoApmYm81iuXoPkFOJwJ8ERdknLPMO" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='css/style.css' />
    <link href="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
<body>

    <div id='calendar'></div>



    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.0.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src='js/moment.js'></script>
    <script src='js/fullcalendar.js'></script>
    <script src='js/scheduler.js'></script>
    <script src='js/my_script.js'></script>

    <script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.4/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
    <script src="https://code.jquery.com/ui/1.12.1/jquery-ui.js"></script>




</body>
</html>
```

JS

```
var resources = [
    {
        id: 'A',
        title: 'A',
        sortOrder: 1
    },
    {
        id: 'B',
        title: 'B',
        sortOrder:2
    },
    {
        id: 'C',
        title: 'C',
        sortOrder:3
    }
];


$('#calendar').fullCalendar({


    // height: 550,
    // eventColor: '#428bca',

    schedulerLicenseKey: 'CC-Attribution-NonCommercial-NoDerivatives',
    defaultView: 'timelineFourDays',

    views: {
        timelineFourDays: {
            type: 'timeline',
            minTime: '07:00:00',
            duration: { days: 4 }
        },
    },

    resources: resourcesFunc,



    nowIndicator: true,




    events: [
        {
            id: '1',
            resourceId: 'A',
            title: 'Meeting',
            start: '2019-07-13T00:20:00',
            end: '2019-07-14T02:20:00',
        },

        {
            id: '2',
            resourceId: 'A',
            title: 'Meeting2',
            start: '2019-07-13T00:20:00',
            end: '2019-07-14T02:20:00',
        }


    ],
    displayEventTime: true,


});


function resourcesFunc(callback) {
    callback(resources);
}
```

[image]

The < should be only if the element is not whole visible on screen. In this case this class is wrongly calculated...

https://jsfiddle.net/Ly9rsoc1/2/

Comment: which version of fullCalendar are you using? Also I can't really understand your issue...can you give a better explanation? All I know is that some elements have got a CSS class which you weren't expecting. Exactly which elements do you mean? What problem does that cause? It would be great to have a proper example with some code and HTML.

Comment: can we have some code and data as a usable example, please? No-one can fix bugs in screenshots. Also it appears you have probably got a bit of custom CSS there...if you remove that and go back to a standard theme, do you still get the same issue?

Comment: Hi, I edit my question,...

Comment: why have you got two different versions of the bootstrap CSS in your page? Just use one copy, the one which matches the version of the bootstrap JS file. I'm not saying that's your issue in this case but clearly it has the potential to cause problems.

Comment: Also you've included jQueryUI but not the related CSS. Again maybe not the direct cause of your problem here, but it's a bit illogical.

Comment: Anyway I made a runnable demo to confirm that this is reproducible: http://jsfiddle.net/d1g3a085/2/. I included correct bootstrap and jQueryUI CSS just to rule those out. So yes I can see the < icons.

Answer (score 0):

You said

> "The < should be only if the element is not whole visible on screen"

However: Your events start before the specified `minTime` value. This means that the start point of the event can never be visible on your calendar. Therefore the `<` icon is displayed.

I think you have misunderstood the nature of this functionality. It's not about whether the start of the **HTML element** is visible, it's about whether the start of the **event** (which is represented by that HTML element) is visible. And since you removed some of the times covered by that event from your display, then it displays the icon so that this fact is clear to the user.

In conclusion: The calendar is behaving exactly as it should. There is no bug here.

---

As an aside,  I would point out that if you routinely have events which cover these times of day, then in my opinion it's not very logical or very user-friendly to make those times invisible, because it hides what might be useful information. But if these particular events are an anomaly, and most of your events are after 7am then you might just have to tolerate these ones as an unusual case.

Comment: I don't agree with you. The default value for minTime is 00.00, but if you have event that go to previous day (and previous day is visible) the < is not visible. And what would < icon be for, if it is displayed even when whole event is visible,...

Comment: "if you have event that go to previous day (and previous day is visible) the < is not visible."... can you give a specific example please, then I can test what you mean?

Comment: just remove the minTime and put one start date one day behind.

Comment: Like this you mean? http://jsfiddle.net/8yoxtkd9/ . When the calendar opens, the < appears because the earlier time is not visible at that moment. Once you scroll far enough back, the < disappears. Again I'm not sure what the issue would be with that? Or this one: http://jsfiddle.net/8yoxtkd9/1/ where the event start occurs on a day not shown on the timeline at all without pressing the "previous" button. Again the < disappears once the start of the event becomes visible. I'm really struggling to understand what you think is wrong.

Comment: Also, you said "what would < icon be for, if it is displayed even when whole event is visible". I agree that would be useless. But that never happens, and I never said it should, so I don't know why you mentioned this.